# How to remove horizontal line from PowerPoint background graphic?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

[image]

It's there in every slide with a title. If I check *'Hide background graphics'* it goes, but also other background graphics I want. How to remove this line only from the background graphics?
[image]

Comment: How is the background created: An image, master slide? Perhaps if you posted the file online (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.) it would help.

Comment: If all the slides have this horizontal line, it's best to go to View tab > Slide Master, then check if there is the line shape.